# Discord.py how to ban a user that isn't a member

Tags: discord.py

```
user=get(ctx.guild.members, name="nameUser")
await ctx.guild.ban(user, reason=None)
```

This is the code I'm using, I'm helping a friend to create a new discord server, but he wants to have the same banned user on both of them. I'm trying to do that, but I only get that error: `Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'`. Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with your question but the error you get there is because there is no member named "nameUser" and your `user` variable will be None (don't name it user it's a member object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User ID is the snowflake integer associated with the user, visit [this support post](https://support.discordapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/206346498-Where-can-I-find-my-User-Server-Message-ID-) to see how to find it

```py
# Use fetch user if the account is not in a guild with the bot
user = await bot.fetch_user(user_id)
await ctx.guild.ban(user, reason="Testing", delete_message_days=0)
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm unable to do so, cause I don't know hoe to get the id of a user that isn't a member of a server.

Comment: Here there is the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60476913/discord-py-how-to-get-the-snowflake-of-a-user-that-isnt-a-member-of-the-server