# Discord.py how to get the snowflake of a user that isn't a member of the server?

Tags: discord.py

```
username="Testing"
BADuser = await bot.fetch_user(username)
await ctx.guild.ban(BADuser, reason="Testing", delete_message_days=0)
```

This is the code I'm using.
I get this error:

```
command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 BAD REQUEST (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In user_id: Value "Testing" is not snowflake.
```

I don't know how to get the snowflake using only the name and the unique number for each user. Cause the users aren't on the server. Thank you for any help.

Comment: It is impossible for the bot to access user snowflakes if they aren't on the same server as the bot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bot cannot find the ID of a user it cannot access, you need the ID to access the user. You can view the docs for this call [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.fetch_user), and this is the only call the library has that lets you access user data that the bot cannot directly communicate with